# Conjunction Rule

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I feel this is a basic question but it has been bugging me.

Suppose I have the following derivation (in intuitionistic logic):

$$(\wedge^{+})\frac{\Gamma_1 \vdash x=1 \hspace{1cm} \Gamma_2 \vdash x=2}{\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \vdash x=1 \wedge x=2}$$

Clearly it's not true that $x=1$ and $x=2$ so the sequent $\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2 \vdash x=1 \wedge x=2$ should not be derivable but I cannot see the rule/axiom which forbids this.

Can someone please explain where exactly this derivation is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is valid.

The points is though that if $\Gamma_1\vdash x=1$ and $\Gamma_2\vdash x=2$ then $\Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$ is inconsistent. However from an inconsistent set we may derive any conclusion, even in intutionistic logic.